# Enumerable OrderBy - are null values always treated high or low and can this be considered stable behaviour?

Tags: c#, sorting, null

I am sorting some `IEnumerable` of objects:

```
var sortedObjects = objects.OrderBy(obj => obj.Member)
```

Where Member is of an `IComparable` type. This sort seems to put objects with `obj.Member == null` at the top. This is roughly the behaviour that I want, but can I consider this to be stable with respect to future .NET frameworks? Is there a way I can make this 'nulls are low' behaviour more explicit?

Comment: "... at the top" & "nulls are low" seem to contradict one another. OTOH interesting question. +1

Comment: You could implement your own OrderBy method.  What exactly are you asking is stable.  Why do you keep a reference to a null object?

Comment: @spender: nulls are low in value, so they are at the top (when sorted from low to high... or ascending).

Comment: @spender that's what I was going for

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To make the behavior more explicit:

```
var sorted = objects.OrderBy(o => o.Member == null).ThenBy(o => o.Member);
```

Comment: Yup. I think this is the clearest/nicest of any solution. +1.

Comment: If you're aware that nulls always compare lower, then this is unnecessary, but it does give you explicit control over whether they appear first or last, regardless of which direction you order non-null values.  Note that the above code actually reverses the default behavior because when Member == null, the value is true (1), causing nulls to be ordered later than non-nulls.

Answer (score 25):

From MSDN for [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx):

> By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) null, and
>   two null references compare equal to each other.

So a null object is considered less than a non-null object. If sorting ascending, you will get nulls first.

Comment: I feel this answers the letter my question well, but I'm going with the consensus and accepting danny chen's answer which makes it explicit with the least knowledge required of the reader

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the overload of OrderBy that takes an [IComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and implement it yourself to codify this expectation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx